# Problems with landscape mode and Title on the same page

Tags: landscape

For an appendix I am trying to create rotated tables and I am using the landscape mode for this. Only one problem is holding me back; As soon as I am trying to add the title of the appendix to the tables I created, either the title is rotated ( see the following code):

```
\begin{landscape}
\section{blabla}
    \begin{table}
     blablabla
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

Or when I write the section name outside the landscape mode, The title starts on an empty page and the tables start on the next page (which is ugly).(see following code):

```
\section{blabla}
\begin{landscape}
     \begin{table}
     blablabla
     \end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: `landscape` always starts a new page. If it is only the table you want to rotate, try `sidewaystable` (I think it is in the `rotating` package). Besides your `title` in the subject is a bit confusing, people might thing a table caption is title instead

Answer (score 2):

How about this...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}

\section{Hello}

My table is in Table~\ref{tab:hello}.
\begin{table}
  \begin{sideways}
    \begin{tabular}{lllllllll}
    hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello \\
    hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello \\
    hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello \\
    hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello \\
    hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello \\
    hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello \\
    hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello \\
    hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello \\
    hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello \\
    hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello \\
    hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello \\
    hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello \\
    hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello \\
    hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello \\
    hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello \\
    hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello
    \end{tabular}
  \end{sideways}
  \centering
  \caption[Caption]{Caption.}
  \label{tab:hello}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This would work indeed, except that I can only get one table on each page ...

Comment: Aha, a new problem. This might be best tackled by you opening a new question. Give a **[minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)** to show the layout problem you're having, and we'll find a solution for you `:-)`.

Answer (score 2):

The [`hvfloat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hvfloat) package is highly flexible and offers you the possibility to have several rotated tables in one page; in the following example I deactivated flotation for all tables, using the `nonFloat=true` option; notice also the `capWidth=w` option so the caption width will be the same as the table width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hvfloat}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section with Several Rotated Objects}

\hvFloat[%
nonFloat=true,%
capWidth=w,%
capPos=t,%
rotAngle=90,%
objectPos=c%
]{table}{%
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    column1a & column2a \\
    column2b & column2b \\
    column1c & column2c \\
    column1d & column2d \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
}{%
A test rotated table}{tab:test1}

\vfill

\hvFloat[%
nonFloat=true,%
capWidth=w,%
capPos=t,%
rotAngle=90,%
objectPos=c%
]{table}{%
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    column1a & column2a \\
    column2b & column2b \\
    column1c & column2c \\
    column1d & column2d \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
}{Another test rotated table}{tab:test2}

\end{document}
```

[image]