# Chapter title and rotated table (with subtables) on the same page

Tags: tables, subfloats, rotating

My problem is quite similar to the one described in [Problems with landscape mode and Title on the same page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118073). The `hvfloats` solution suggested there does not work for me, however, because I use multiple `subtable`s. But let me start from the beginning:

In the appendix of my thesis I want to add a wide table that needs to be set in landscape mode. Normally I'd just use the `sidewaystable` environment, but that leaves the first page of the appendix completely empty except for the chapter heading

```
\documentclass[a4paper] {scrbook}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\appendix \cleardoublepage
\chapter{Some Data Tables}

\begin{sidewaystable}
  \hspace*{\fill}
  \begin{subtable}{.3\textwidth}
    \rule{\linewidth}{12cm}
  \end{subtable}
  %
  \hspace*{\fill}
  %
  \begin{subtable}{.3\textwidth}
    \rule{\linewidth}{12cm}
  \end{subtable}
  \hspace*{\fill}

  \caption{Table with interesting data}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

The purpose of the three `\hspace*{\fill}` is just to center the resulting tables properly on the page.

---

Realising that `sidewaystable` refers to `\textheight` I also tried to temporarily adjust that

```
\def \textheightTmp \textheight
\def \textheight 0.8\textheightTmp
\begin{sidewaystable}
  [...]
\end{sidewaystable}
\def \textheight \textheightTmp
```

but this lead to the following error

> Appendix A.
>
> ! Package caption Error: \setcaptionsubtype outside float.
>
> See the caption package documentation for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.
>    ...
>
> l.15       \begin{subtable}{.3\textwidth}

---

As I mentioned at the beginning, `hvfloats` does not work either because of the `subtable`s

```
\documentclass[a4paper] {scrbook}

\usepackage{hvfloat}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\appendix \cleardoublepage
\chapter{Some Data Tables}

\hvFloat[capPos=b,rotAngle=90,nonFloat]{table}{%
  \hspace*{\fill}
  \begin{subtable}{.3\textwidth}
    \rule{\linewidth}{12cm}
  \end{subtable}
  %
  \hspace*{\fill}
  %
  \begin{subtable}{.3\textwidth}
    \rule{\linewidth}{12cm}
  \end{subtable}
  \hspace*{\fill}
}{Table with interesting data}{}

\end{document}
```

This results in the error:

> Appendix A.
>
> ! Package caption Error: \setcaptionsubtype outside float.
>
> See the caption package documentation for explanation.
>   Type  H   for immediate help.
>    ...
>
> l.23     }{Table with interesting data}{}

---

What I want is a rotated table (with subtables) and caption that is placed on the same page as the chapter heading. Space isn't an issue, the table would fit on the page.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `hvfloat` does work properly when I replace `subtable` with `minipage` and set the subcaptions manually with `\captionof{subtable}`. But then there are 3 new problems:
1. spacing is not correct (too much space between table and subcaption and between subcaption and caption)
2. the subcaption format is not consistent with that of regular `subtable`s
3. all (some?) the `hspace` commands are ignored and the tables are off center and very close together

Comment: I continued my experiments with `hvfloat` and just loading the package is enough to distort the caption spacing of tables that comprise subtables :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are facing two problems here:

1. The `hvfloat` package does not set `\@captype` (like an ordinary floating environment does) so the `subcaption` package has no idea if its commands are used inside a `figure`, a `table`, or not within a floating environment at all. This must be fixed by Herbert, however you could use `\captionsetup{type=table}` as workaround.
2. The standard document classes set `\abovecaptionskip` to a value of 10pt, `\belowcaptionskip` to 0pt. `\abovecaptionskip` will be used above the caption, and `\belowcaptionskip` below of it. However, this gives you a obvious problem when a `\caption` is typeset above a figure or table content since you will get a distance of `\belowcaptionskip` (=0pt) between caption and content, i.e. no distance of all. There are two different (and incompatible) ways to resolve this situation:

   - `\abovecaptionskip` will be used between caption and content, `\belowcaptionskip` will be used between caption and edge of the floating environment. (This has the advantage that you could use the default values of `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip` as set by the document class, and the result will not change at all when using `\caption` below its contents, as designed by Leslie Lamport.)
   - If the caption is below its content, only `\abovecaptionskip` is used. If the caption is above its content, only `\belowcaptionskip` is used. (The skips need to be adjusted for making this work, but you are able to setup different skips for above-captions and below-captions here.)

As you see both methods have its pros and cons, but are unfortunately incompatible. However, KOMA-Script and the (sub)`caption` package are using the first method while `hvfloat` seems to use the latter. (I'm not sure about this since I didn't have found the time to look into Herbers sources, but at least `hvfloat` changes the values of the caption skips and therefore just loading the package will affect the skips of the non-hvfloat-floating environments (and the `longtable` environment and...) as well.)

To compensate this one needs to write macros to save and restore the skips.

So in total we have:

```
\documentclass[a4paper] {scrbook}

% Save the values of \abovecaptionskip and \belowcaptionskip into \restorecaptionskips
\edef\restorecaptionskips{%
  \noexpand\setlength\noexpand\abovecaptionskip{\the\abovecaptionskip}%
  \noexpand\setlength\noexpand\belowcaptionskip{\the\belowcaptionskip}}
%\show\restorecaptionskips
\usepackage{hvfloat}
% Save the changed values of \abovecaptionskip and \belowcaptionskip into \restorehvcaptionskips
\edef\restorehvcaptionskips{%
  \noexpand\setlength\noexpand\abovecaptionskip{\the\abovecaptionskip}%
  \noexpand\setlength\noexpand\belowcaptionskip{\the\belowcaptionskip}}
% Restore the values of \abovecaptionskip and \belowcaptionskip
\restorecaptionskips

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\appendix \cleardoublepage
\chapter{Some Data Tables}

\restorehvcaptionskips % only needed if "capPos=t"
\hvFloat[capPos=b,rotAngle=90,nonFloat]{table}{%
\restorecaptionskips
\captionsetup{type=table}% set \@captype
  \hspace*{\fill}
  \begin{subtable}{.3\textwidth}
    \rule{\linewidth}{12cm}
  \end{subtable}
  %
  \hspace*{\fill}
  %
  \begin{subtable}{.3\textwidth}
    \rule{\linewidth}{12cm}
  \end{subtable}
  \hspace*{\fill}
}{Table with interesting data}{}
\restorecaptionskips

\end{document}
```

P.S.: See also http://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/4/

Comment: Thanks for the detailled explanation! I think `\noexpand\setlength\noexpand\abovecaptionskip{\the\belowcaptionskip}` should actually read `\noexpand\setlength\noexpand\belowcaptionskip{\the\belowcaptionskip}`. Otherwise it doesn't make much sense. The `hspace` commands are still ignored, but I think I can live with that.

Comment: It just occured to me that the `hspace` is likely not working because the `hvFloat` just cannot know the size I expect it to fill. I will try and add an additional `minipage` that has this size and contains the actual table...

Comment: @TableKing Yes, of course you are correct, will correct the answer right now.