# Keeping section headers and rotated images on the same page

Tags: pdftex

I have a similar problem like the one here:

[Problems with landscape mode and Title on the same page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118073/problems-with-landscape-mode-and-title-on-the-same-page)

Unfortunately, I'm trying to include images, which doesn't seem to work this way.

I've tried the following as proposed in one of the answers to the question above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hvfloat}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section with Several Rotated Objects}

\hvFloat[%
nonFloat=true,%
capWidth=w,%
capPos=t,%
rotAngle=90,%
objectPos=c%
]\begin{figure}
\centering
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\setlength\fboxrule{0.5pt}
\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.5,trim=33 355 137 50, clip=true]{image1}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5,trim=55 135 65 135, clip=true]{image2}}
\caption{caption.}
\label{img:caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But this returns the error:

```
! Argument of \caption@ydblarg has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
            \par 
l.12    \setlength
            \fboxsep{0pt}
```

Could someone point me in the right direction, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the documentation of [hvfloat](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hvfloat) as you have not used anything of it's syntax.

The source for your example should be:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hvfloat}

\begin{document}    
    \section{Test Section with Several Rotated Objects} 
    \hvFloat[%
    nonFloat=true,%
    capWidth=w,%
    capPos=t,%
    rotAngle=90,%
    objectPos=c%
    ]{figure}{%
        \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
        \setlength\fboxrule{0.5pt}
        \fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.5,trim=33 355 137 50, clip=true]{image1}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5,trim=55 135 65 135, clip=true]{image2}}
    }{caption.}{img:caption}
\end{document}
```