# How to put the appendix chapter and landscape tables on the same page?

Tags: tables, landscape, appendix

I'm trying to put the section and subsection titles (**Appendices** and **400h EIS fitting results**) on the same page with two landscape tables. I found several answers on this community but none of them satisfied me. I would like to keep the `landscape` environment if possible, avoiding `sideways` or `minipage`... (PS: Do not take care about the table size of 14cm, If necessary I can reduce it more)

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
\section{400h EIS fitting results}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{EIS fitting result for Blank sample using the R(Q(R(QR) model for the ECC.}
\label{tab:FitBlank}
\resizebox{14cm}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccccc@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{9}{c}{\textbf{EIS fitting results for Blank sample}}                         \\ \midrule
Hour &
  $\text{R}_{sol}$ $\left[\si{\ohm\square\centi\metre}\right]$ &
  $\text{R}_{ox}$ $\left[\si{\ohm\square\centi\metre}\right]$ &
  $\text{R}_{ct}$ $\left[\si{\ohm\square\centi\metre}\right]$ &
  $\text{CPE}_{del}$ $\left[\si{\siemens\second^{a}\per\centi\metre\squared}\right]$ &
  $a_{del}$ &
  $\text{CPE}_{ox}$ $\left[\si{\siemens\second^{a}\per\centi\metre\squared}\right]$ &
  $a_{ox}$ &
  GoF, $\chi^2$ \\
0   & 305.2    & 409.4e3 & 81.16e3 & 1.810e-6 & 1.000    & 3.826e-6 & 881.6e-3 & 12.35e-3 \\
24  & 121.3    & 1.288e3 & 122.1e3 & 693.2e-9 & 945.8e-3 & 4.164e-6 & 969.2e-3 & 9.629e-3 \\
48  & 135.6    & 520.6   & 116.1e3 & 2.468e-6 & 798.5e-3 & 3.265e-6 & 1.000    & 3.087e-3 \\
72  & 84.68    & 2.236e3 & 81.87e3 & 534.9e-9 & 968.0e-3 & 4.766e-6 & 961.1e-3 & 6.641e-3 \\
96  & 99.50    & 263.5   & 201.6e3 & 2.928e-6 & 834.8e-3 & 3.145e-6 & 1.000    & 1.435e-3 \\
168 & 93.97    & 35.19e3 & 50.86e3 & 229.4e-6 & 974.3e-3 & 9.069e-6 & 949.8e-3 & 9.762e-3 \\
216 & 103.7    & 58.00e3 & 50.41e3 & 170.6e-6 & 1.000    & 9.270e-6 & 952.3e-3 & 519.2e-6 \\
264 & 949.2e-9 & 93.71   & 8.118e9 & 8.052e-6 & 978.5e-3 & 15.81e-6 & 200.5e-3 & 2.604e-3 \\
336 & 114.0    & 72.62e3 & 143.7e3 & 77.27e-6 & 856.1e-3 & 9.656e-6 & 953.0e-3 & 436.5e-6 \\
400 & 96.88    & 74.81e3 & 215.6e3 & 63.07e-6 & 817.4e-3 & 9.859e-6 & 952.7e-3 & 428.7e-6 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{EIS fitting result for C6-1 sample using the R(Q(R(QR) model for the ECC.}
\label{tab:FitC6-1}
\resizebox{14cm}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccccc@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{9}{c}{\textbf{EIS fitting results C6-1 sample}}                             \\ \midrule
Hour &
  $\text{R}_{sol}$ $\left[\si{\ohm\square\centi\metre}\right]$ &
  $\text{R}_{ldh}$ $\left[\si{\ohm\square\centi\metre}\right]$ &
  $\text{R}_{ct}$ $\left[\si{\ohm\square\centi\metre}\right]$ &
  $\text{CPE}_{ox}$ $\left[\si{\siemens\second^{a}\per\centi\metre\squared}\right]$ &
  $a_{ox}$ &
  $\text{CPE}_{ldh}$ $\left[\si{\siemens\second^{a}\per\centi\metre\squared}\right]$ &
  $a_{ldh}$ &
  GoF, $\chi^2$ \\
0   & 104.5 & 1.717e3  & 11.41e6 & 670.1e-15 & 34.21e-3 & 3.382e-6 & 938.8e-3 & 3.382e-3 \\
24  & 153.5 & 56.79    & 1.014e6 & 1.988e-6  & 935.1e-3 & 1.306e-6 & 983.6e-3 & 212.5e-6 \\
48  & 164.6 & 155.6    & 637.1e3 & 1.201e-6  & 967.2e-3 & 2.002e-6 & 975.3e-3 & 4.240e-3 \\
72  & 121.1 & 17.98e-6 & 373.0e3 & 1.538e-12 & 966.2e-3 & 3.482e-6 & 969.3e-3 & 3.353e-3 \\
96  & 128.0 & 28.90    & 284.3e3 & 2.661e-6  & 966.3e-3 & 1.366e-6 & 974.2e-3 & 755.2e-6 \\
168 & 135.1 & 3.775e3  & 220.5e3 & 957.8e-9  & 999.7e-3 & 4.049e-6 & 991.1e-3 & 9.180e-3 \\
216 & 142.3 & 3.803e3  & 172.4e3 & 1.109e-6  & 999.0e-3 & 4.110e-6 & 991.8e-3 & 7.683e-3 \\
264 & 131.7 & 4.909e3  & 91.36e3 & 1.486e-6  & 1.000    & 4.168e-6 & 998.3e-3 & 76.42e-3 \\
336 & 155.3 & 3.566e3  & 243.9e3 & 1.399e-6  & 999.5e-3 & 3.859e-6 & 1.000    & 15.04e-3 \\
400 & 137.8 & 236.5e3  & 25.21e3 & 1.668e-6  & 1.000    & 6.152e-6 & 949.6e-3 & 5.573e-3 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

The result is represented below:

[image: First page]
[image: Second page]

Comment: did you try (just in case) with a really small table or image? just write down a fake one for testing purposes. Is the behavior the same?

Comment: The `landscape` environment always starts a  new page.

Comment: Here is a solution using the `hvfloat` package: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118122/134144